# Deploying app in android with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have phonegap install in my pc, the drivers of my android are installed as well

now i run:

```
phonegap run android
```

from within the project directory

"Waiting for emulator" message is recieved

how can i deploy the app directly to my android?

Comment: You must connect it to your PC using USB cable.

Comment: it's connected, and all drivers are installed

Comment: once it's connected and i run the above command, shouldn't it automatically install it to my android? (of course development options are enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the device is not conectect... 
maybe the ADB driver is not working on the PC...
or you don't enable the **USB debugging** option on the device.

On the command line write: **adb devices**.